# Method Error: No method matching (::var"#31#32")(::Pair{String, String})

Tags: julia

I am wondering how to filter a dictionary, when I try to use `filter()` function I. get the following errors.

```
some_dict = Dict("apple" => "green", "pumpkin" => "yellow", "grape" => "green")
filter((k,v) -> v == "green", some_dict)

>>> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#37#38")(::Pair{String, String})
Closest candidates are:
  (::var"#37#38")(::Any, !Matched::Any) at ~/github/CRTT-lite/crtt_lite_osm.jl:83
```

Comment: Are you curious about the filter function? If not, maybe it would be not a bad idea to use list comprehensions like `[key_value for key_value in pairs(some_dict) if key_value[2]=="green"]`.

Comment: Thanks for this and I know how to do it using list comprehension. I was more curious why filter function isn't working

Comment: Yes, **I said** "If not...".

Answer (score 1):

For dictionary filter accept `(k,v)` as a pair, so for checking if `v` is equal something you can use

```
filter(d->d.second == "green", some_dict)
```

Comment: Can you please interpret `d->d.second`?

Comment: `d -> d.second == "green"` creates an anonymous  function where `d` is its argument and `d.second == "green"` is its body.